# How to alternate between login screen types in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, user-accounts, login

When already at the default login screen in Windows 7 where you click on an icon to select a user, is there a way to switch to the mode where you enter both a username and a password?

[In Windows XP, this was done by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> twice.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050914-16/?p=34203)

I know that you can change the default to the mode where you enter both a username and password, by enabling the group policy "*Do not display last user name*". That is not the point of the question!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.

In Windows 7 you you either enable or disable the Secure Log On, as explained [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/612-secure-logon-press-ctrl-alt-delete-log.html), but you cannot switch between them by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>,